# Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter - UnsatisfiedDependencyException in Spring

Tags: java, spring, exception

I'm stuck trying to create a Spring boot application that performs basic CRUD operations by using Spring. The idea is that I have my FlightServiceImpl class execute the request originally ran in the main method to take the values of its parameter and store them in a Map as a way to simulate a database since there is a Key/Value pair combination. However, I can't seem to get through this exception and I don't know why. I've copied the stack trace and pasted it below:

"Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'flightServiceImpl' defined in file [**/AirlineTicketManager/AirlineFlightManager/target/classes/com/tbonegames/services/FlightServiceImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: No qualifying bean of type 'com.tbonegames.repository.FlightRepositoryImpl' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}

If you have any advice. I'd greatly appreciate it.

```java
package com.tbonegames.AirlineFlightManager;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;

import com.tbonegames.repository.FlightRepositoryImpl;
import com.tbonegames.services.FlightServiceImpl;

@SpringBootApplication
public class AirlineFlightManagerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AirlineFlightManagerApplication.class, args);
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
        //ApplicationContext context = new ApplicationContext();
        context.scan("com.tbonegames.services");
        context.refresh();

        FlightRepositoryImpl fri = context.getBean(FlightRepositoryImpl.class);

        FlightServiceImpl fsi = context.getBean(FlightServiceImpl.class);

        fsi.addFlight("1004", "American Airlines", "Chicago", "Miami", 125.00, 3);
    }

}

package com.tbonegames.services;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.tbonegames.flights.Flight;
import com.tbonegames.repository.FlightRepositoryImpl;

@Component
public class FlightServiceImpl extends Flight implements FlightService {

    //autowiring the reference of the FlightRepositoryImpl
    @Autowired
    private FlightRepositoryImpl fri;

    //constructor of the service class that takes in the FlightRepository
    //The @Autowired annotation is used for the constructor of a class. 
    @Autowired
    public FlightServiceImpl(FlightRepositoryImpl fri) {
        this.fri = fri;
    }
    
    ArrayList <FlightflightList = new ArrayList<>();
    Flight flight;
    
    /*Adding a flight must have the user's Details  
    private String flightId;
    private String airlines;
    private String source;
    private String destination;
    private Double fare;
    private LocalDate journeyDate;
    private Integer seatCount;
    */
        
    public void addFlight(String flightId) {

    }
    
    @Override
    @Bean
    public String generateFlightID(String flightId) {
        String currentFlight = flightId;
        if (flightId == null) {
            this.setFlightId("1001");
        else {
            int in = 1001;
            for (int i = 0; i < flightList.size(); i++) {
                int tempInt = Integer.parseInt(flightList.get(i).getFlightId());
                if (in == tempInt) {
                    in++;
                }

            }
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append(in);
            currentFlight = sb.toString();
        }
        return currentFlight;
    }
    
    @Bean
    public void searchFlight(String flightInfo) {
        fri.search(flightInfo);
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public void addFlight(String flightId, String airlines, String source, String destination, Double fare, Integer seatCount) {

        flight = new Flight();
        flight.setFlightId(generateFlightID(flightId));
        flight.setAirlines(airlines);
        flight.setSource(source);
        flight.setDestination(destination);
        flight.setFare(fare);
        flight.setSeatCount(seatCount);
        fri.store(flight);
    }

}
```

I was expecting the program to run and execute the code, storing the values in the map, allowing me to simulate CRUD operations around flight data.

Comment: Whilst I was formatting your code, I noticed that the `if` block in `generateFlightID` `if (flightId == null) { this.setFlightId("1001"); else { int in = 1001;` doesn't have a closing brace!

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Thank you for formatting your code properly. Upon looking at it again, the problem is that you need to define an implementation of `FlightRepositoryImpl` with the `@Component` annotation somewhere in your application code. Once you do this, Spring will be able to autowire the component into your bean and everything should work properly.